# How to convert image file object to numpy array in with openCv python?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, flask

I am developing API to upload Image using Flask. After uploading i want to modify image using openCV, As openCV requires numpy array object to i have file object, how do i convert to numpy array?
Here is my code

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def enroll_user():
    file = request.files['fileName']
    # file.save(os.path.join(file.filename))
    return response
```

**Edit:** updated code

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
    def enroll_user():
        file = request.files['fileName']
        response = file.read()
        # file.save(os.path.join(file.filename))
        return response
```

I want to convert file to cv2 frame as i get with below code

```
ret, frame = cv2.imread(file)
```

One way is to write image to disk and read again with cv2.imread but i don't want to do that because it will be time consuming. So is there any way to convert to cv2 frame from file object?

Thanks

Comment: Something like [this](https://gist.github.com/kylehounslow/767fb72fde2ebdd010a0bf4242371594)?

Comment: Could you share the code sending the http request please?

Comment: `OpenCV` image object **is** numpy object, generally with dtype `np.uint8`.

Comment: @QuangHoang You are right, OpenCV image object is numpy object, but i want to convert uploaded jpg file to OpenCV image object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you effectively have the contents of a JPEG/PNG file in your variable called `response`, I think you can do:

```
frame = cv2.imdecode(response)
```

Or, you may need to do:

```
frame = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(response, np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

Failing that, another way is like this:

```
from io import BytesIO
from scipy import misc

frame = misc.imread(BytesIO(response))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried with imdecode, but it requires flag as second argument so i have passed cv2.IMREAD_COLOR but now i am getting Error: frame = cv2.imdecode(file, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
TypeError: buf is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

Comment: I also tried your second method,which gives me a following Error: frame = misc.imread(BytesIO(img))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'FileStorage'

Comment: I updated my answer, please try new, second option. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, the updated option works for me, but before that i need to read the file which i haven't done. As in my updated question.

Comment: Cool. Glad we got you up and running - sorry it took me so long. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

If the `file` is in read-byte mode (which means `mode='rb'`) in your case, then [`numpy.frombuffer()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html) also works, for example :

```py
file = request.files['fileName']
frame = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(file.read(), numpy.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```